# Establishing transfer function for s = f(e)

Tags: diodes, current-limiting

I'm preparing for a test this Wednesday and I'm stuck on this exercise:

[Ud1 = voltage across D1; Ud2 = voltage across D2; e = in voltage; s = out voltage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woOgR.jpg)
[image]

I need to study 4 cases:

1. Both are blocked
2. Neither are blocked
3. D1 is not blocked, D2 is blocked
4. D1 is blocked, D2 is not

As you can see I started with D1 is not blocked, D2 is blocked, but I have no idea where to start. I tried representing D1 and D2 accordingly (Vt = 0.6V), but what should I do next? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Sum the voltage around the loop: e = E1 + Vd + s => s = e - E1 + Vd. The condition is that D1 is conducting and therefore the current you labeled I must be positive, therefore s must be positive for this relationship to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, I'll give the example of D1 closed (not blocked) and D2 open (blocked).

As can be seen in the image below, a closed diode behaves like a voltage source of Vt Volts while a blocked diode behaves like an open switch:

[image]

Exercice Data:
$$
V_T = 0.6V \\
E_1 = E_2 = 1V
$$

Using KVL we have:
$$
s = e - V{_d{_1}} - E_1 \\
I = I_1 = (e - V{_d{_1}} - E_1)/R \\
$$

And the fact that D1 is closed and D2 is open means that:
$$
V{_d{_1}} = V{_T} \rightarrow I_1 > 0 \\
I_2 = 0 \rightarrow V{_d{_2}} < V_T           
$$

Replacing Vd1, Vd2 and I1 with their formulas we get:
$$
e - s - E1 = V_T \rightarrow (e - V{_d{_1}} - E_1)/R > 0 \\
I_2 = 0 \rightarrow s - e - E_2 < V_T
$$

In the end that leaves us with:
$$
s = e - E_1 - V_T \rightarrow e > V{_d{_1}} + E_1 \\
I_2 = 0 \rightarrow s < e + E_2 + V_t
$$

The result is given to us by the numerical application:
$$
e > 1.6V \\
s = e - 1.6V
$$

This should be correct and all the other cases are similar. If this is not correct, please notify.